# What is the limit of $\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)$$

I assume that I have to calculate with the L'Hospital rule but I don't know how does it work in this case.

Comment: If you only want a hint I'd say this: Remember how to subtract fractions! ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{-1+x-\ln(x)}{\ln(x)(x-1)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(-1+x-\ln(x)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\ln(x)(x-1)\right)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{x-1}{x}+\ln(x)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x-1}{-1+x+x\ln(x)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x-1\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(-1+x+x\ln(x)\right)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1}{2+\ln(x)}\right)$$

You can complete it I think!

Comment: How is this a *hint* if it solves the whole task? All you need to do it plug in $x$ now, a completely trivial operation

Comment: I didn't tell him to derive the functions using L'Hospital's rule

Comment: Of course you did. Line 3 => line 4 does exactly that...

Answer (score 3):

HINT: consider $$\frac{x-1-\log(x)}{(x-1)\log(x)}$$ and use L'Hospital

Answer (score 2):

Use L'Hospital's rule.

First, simplify the expression by writing it as $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ (where you are tasked with finding $f$ and $g$).

Then, you can calculate the limit as $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is better to simplify a bit before applying L'Hospital's Rule. Thus we have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{\log x} - \frac{1}{x - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h - \log(1 + h)}{h\log(1 + h)}\text{ (putting }x = 1 + h)\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{h - \log(1 + h)}{h^{2}\cdot\dfrac{\log(1 + h)}{h}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h - \log(1 + h)}{h^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + h}}{2h}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{1 + h}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\notag
\end{align}